# Belgium visa for dependent mother?

Tags: belgium, family

I'm working in a software company in India; next month, I'm going to Belgium on a work permit. I want to take my widowed mother with me (I'm the only son).

Is there any other visa apart from tourist visa for her? If so, what's the procedure?

Comment: Someone has voted to close this as off topic, in favor of [Expatriates.SE], which is probably where it belongs.  I will flag it for migration.

Comment: @user1995151: I am facing a similar situation. Could you please provide an update of your situation now? I would really appreciate any help whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you and your mother, it seems that she can't qualify for a family visa:

> A non EU ascendant can  not rejoin for instance his non EU son working in Belgium.

*Ascendant* means parent, grandparent, and so on.

Source: http://www.commissioner.brussels/i-am-an-expat/residence-formalities/non-ue-citizen/79-residence-formalities-non-ue/86-family-reunification

Note that your situation corresponds with the "second situation" covered by that page, "a non-EU citizen rejoins a non-EU citizen."  (In the first case, dependent ascendants *are* included, but that does not apply to you because you are not an EU citizen.)

Comment: @mkennedy but the first situation is "A non EU citizen rejoins a EU citizen." That does not apply in this case, which instead corresponds to the second situation, "A non EU citizen rejoins a non EU citizen."

Comment: Thank you, that was stupid of me. I'll delete my first comment, then this one, shortly.

Comment: @mkennedy if you missed that then others will.  I'll edit the answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: thanks for your comments  so the only visa option I have is (https://dofi.ibz.be/sites/dvzoe/EN/Application-guides/Pages/Short_stay_for_private_reasons_Visiting_family_or_friends.aspx)  But what are the possibilities of getting this visa for maximum duration

Comment: @user1995151 I'm afraid I don't know anything about the probability of success or about how it relates to the planned duration of the visit.